# More efficient way to check if a user is in a group that itself belongs to another group?

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

We have groups that represent where the user is providing coverage, each user belongs to one group. Rather than put this in a database table that needs to be maintained I am trying to use the Microsoft Graph API. It is working well, except it now takes 10-12 seconds to load the page where this is done. When I pull this out, it's down to 3 seconds which is because of another API, so I believe it to be the culprit.

So let's say user Jane belongs to "NorthEast" group, which belongs to "Regions" group. So right now I am getting a list of the groups that belong to "Regions" then I am iterating through each user's groups (the big slow down is here) to see if any of them match a group that belongs to "Regions". If one does, then that is their assigned region.

I see MemberOf as a returned item in the list of groups that belong to "Region" but it is always NULL.

List of groups that belong to "Regions":

```
        var members = await graphClient
            .Groups["RegionGroupID"]
            .Members
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();
```

List of a user's groups:

```
            var memberOf = await graphClient
            .Users[UserId]
            .MemberOf
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear about your business logic, but as you said that you need to get all the "Regions" groups first, and then get all the groups of a specific user, then you may need to use "double for loop" to check if this user has a group which is one of the "Regions" groups.

And you said that the big slow down is here so I think you may try to add the "Region" group value to each user so that you can get the value directly. Let's see [user property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) in graph api. How do you think that you set the "Region" group value to `officeLocation or streetAddress`? You may go to azure portal to edit them for each user and you can also get this property by graph api.

[image]

Comment: Using something like officeLocation or streetAddress would definitely be the most efficient since I'm already pulling that information to generate the list of users, but it would require maintaining that information where the groups are already being maintained for other processes.

I have improved the efficiency by running the foreach where it grabs the user's groups in parallel, so that might be my best option. I was just curious if there is a way to grab the data without making a call for each user but I don't see anything.

Comment: yes, you have to make a call, or decode id token when signed in